# change value of param based on input value passed

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have controller as follows

```
def city
  params.require(:id)
  begin
    @data = @user.city_details(Integer(params[:id]),
                              params[:flag]
  rescue ArgumentError => e
    render_error(:bad_request, e.message)
  end
end
```

model.rb

```
  def city_details(id, flag = 'N')
    StoredProcedure::User::GetCityDetails.exec!(
        id,
        flag
    )
  end
end
```

so you can see in model i have flag value default 'N'. How do i update controller so that if flag value is passed as true then update it to Y and if passed false then update it to N?

Answer (score 1):

```
flag = params[:flag] == '1' ? 'Y' : 'N'
@data = @user.city_details(params[:id].to_i, flag)
```

I assume that you have some sort of checkbox that will return '1' for true and '0' for false (usual case in rails). If not, alter `params[:flag] == '1'` condition to your needs.